# How to compose Material UI components with React and Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I would like to create an extension of a component from the [Material UI](https://material-ui.com) library. For example, I am always adding styles to the wrapper in a modal, so I would like to create a custom component encapsulating those styles.

I've found the following solution that "works" but I feel like the props interface is a bit of a hack. Is there a better way to do this? Specifically, what is the best way to merge the `classes` prop from the original `<Modal>` component with the classes from my custom `styles` object?

```
import { Modal, WithStyles, createStyles, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import { ModalClassKey, ModalProps } from '@material-ui/core/Modal';
import * as React from 'react';

interface IProps
  extends WithStyles<typeof styles | ModalClassKey>,
    Omit<ModalProps, 'classes'> {}

const styles = createStyles({
  modal: {
    // Some styles to apply to the modal content
  },
});

const MyModal: React.SFC<IProps> = ({ children, classes, ...props }) => (
  <Modal {...props}>
    <div className={classes.modal}>
      {children}
    </div>
  </Modal>
);

export default withStyles(styles)(MyModal);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use className on a material UI component.

I.E

```
<Typography className="large-text">
LORE IPSUM large
</Typography>
```

Comment: This does not answer my question. My question is regarding merging of interface properties with Typescript or a method to get around that. If you can explain how this answer solves that problem, I would be willing to consider it.